# addEventListener not working with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, addeventlistener

I have been trying to fix this problem for a while to no avail. the button on the page was working fine, when I only had one price. so, basically you click on the price and quantity and it adds to the subtotal, total. but once I added a second item and changed the id to a class, and on submitButton = document.querySelectorAll('.input-submit'); I changed from querySelector to querySelectorAll, I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: submitButton.addEventListener is not a function ...not sure why... any help would be appreciate it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
var cart = {};
var ItemNode, quantityNode, costNode, submitButton, subtotalNode, totalNode, output;

function init(){
 itemNode = document.querySelector('.input-item');
 costNode = document.querySelector('.posterPrice');
 quantityNode = document.querySelector('.qtyValue');
 submitButton = document.querySelectorAll('.input-submit');
 subtotalNode = document.getElementById('subtotal');
 totalNode = document.querySelector('#total');
 output = document.querySelector('.output');
 
 
 submitButton.addEventListener('click', addPrice);
}



function addPrice(){
 //addToCart(costNode.innerText, quantityNode.value);
 //console.log(cart);
 console.log('clicked');
}

// function addToCart(cost, quantity){
//  //cart[item] = {};
//  var itemObject = cart;

//  itemObject["quantity"] = Number(quantity);
//  itemObject["cost"] = Number(cost);

//  //var itemTotal = cart["quantity"] * cart["cost"];
//  console.log(itemTotal);
 
//  for (var i = 0; i < itemTotal.length; i++){
//   //subtotalNode.innerHTML = itemTotal++;
//   //totalNode.innerHTML = itemTotal++;
//  }
 
 //console.log(itemTotal);

//}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Gallery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id='test'>Posters</h1>
 <div class="posters">
  <div id="poster1">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">2.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="poster2">
   <div class="posterInfo">
    <p>Price: $<span class="posterPrice">3.50</span></p>
    <label for="qty" class="input-quantity">QTY:</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" class="qtyValue">
    <button class="input-submit">Add to Cart</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="poster3"></div>
  <div id="poster4"></div>
  <div id="poster5"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="total output">
  <p>Subtotal: $<span id="subtotal"></span></p>
  <p>Taxes: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Shipping: <span>$10.00</span></p>
  <p>Total: $<span id="total"></span></p> 
 </div>
 <!--<script src="main.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Array.from(submitButton).forEach(function(ele){ ele.addEventListener('click', addPrice); });`

Comment: Because, `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which does not have `addEventListener` method..